# Canonical question closed by moderator - does not tab-complete in comments

Tags: discussion, canonical

The question [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java) was asked in '08 and became the "NoClassDefFound" canonical answer for duplicates to point to.

It was closed by the moderator BoltClock in summer 2014 who apparently both missed this fact but also never revisited the question even if explicitly asked to in a comment.

EDIT:  *I tried starting to write a comment to ping BoltClock by typing `@Bol` and Tab to complete it, but it didn't work.*

Normally I expect user names "involved" with a question to be tab-completable so you know that 1) the name is correct and 2) that they will be notified, but the closing moderator is apparently not so it is not easy to provide feedback.

I would like a moderator action to imply at least *some* kind of attachment to a given question, so we can provide feedback.

(also it would be nice if the question was reopened and then assigned canonical status)

Comment: You can still use it as the canonical target despite it being closed. Looking at the answers I'm not thrilled about the quality but that might be the standard in [tag:java] (j/k).

Comment: You can still ping him via comments.  They do not autocomplete, but you can manually type it.

Comment: No need, I've seen this question. I'm writing a response.

Comment: It's open again now. The close reason of "must include code to reproduce" shouldn't apply to generic canonical questions. The [canonical nullreferenceexception one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/73226) doesn't include this either.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, I had left a couple of comments on the question at the time I closed it, so I should have been notified of that comment, and tab completion should have assisted you. For whatever reason, it looks like another moderator deleted my comments relatively recently, but not the previous one that was also addressed to me. I don't remember if I missed that comment, or if I saw it and ignored it. In any case, I apologize for not following up on it sooner.

Here's what I said:

[image]

As I stated in my comments above, I was always on the fence about this particular question. I agree that canonical questions don't necessarily require non-working code for context, and so they shouldn't have to be closed for that reason. Now that you've posted here, and requested on the side that the question be reopened, I've gone ahead and done just that. There is no way to explicitly designate a question as canonical for the purposes of duplicates.

Note that even despite my comments being deleted, you should still have been able to ping me the normal way. You can always ping a moderator who closed a question, even though tab completion doesn't appear to pick up their name. Alternatively, you could flag the question for moderator attention so all of us will see it, but I'll be honest: I think other moderators would have agreed with the question being closed, and declined your flag for that reason.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  Interesting that the autocompletion did not work.  I could not see these deleted comments on the question - is this moderator only or do I need 100k or more?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: You're welcome. Only moderators can see deleted comments.

Comment: Regarding the edit - I did not try typing in @BoltClock manually to ping you.